# How to read a file character by character in VB script

Tags: vbscript

How can we read the text file character by character using VB script

Comment: Downvoted; please make an effort to make the question title reflect the question content.

Answer (score 2):

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

Set objFile = objFSO.OpenTextFile("C:\File.txt", 1)
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters = objFile.Read(1)
    Wscript.Echo strCharacters
Loop
```

Answer (score 0):

To set the file path and open the text file..

```
fileName = "D:\Project\ABC\vbfile.txt"

Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set f = fso.OpenTextFile(fileName)
```

Now to read it line by line, use below code

```
Do Until f.AtEndOfStream
  WScript.Echo f.ReadLine
Loop
```

In order to read it character by character use this code

```
Do Until objFile.AtEndOfStream
    strCharacters = f.Read(1)
    Wscript.Echo strCharacters
Loop
```